# Submit record for default approval process via Apex

Tags: apex, approval-process

I am currently trying to approve a record via Apex.

I have been following this example shown here

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_process_example.htm

The actual code for approving is

```
// Create an approval request for the account
Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
req1.setComments('Submitting request for approval.');
req1.setObjectId(a.id);
//Submit on behalf of a specific submitter
req1.setSubmitterId(user1.Id);
// Submit the record to specific process and skip the criteria evaluation
req1.setProcessDefinitionNameOrId('PTO_Request_Process');
req1.setSkipEntryCriteria(true);
// Submit the approval request for the account
Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
```

Is there any way by which I can just submit the record for a default approval process instead of a specific process ?

Comment: Have you tried simply removing the line which calls `setProcessDefinitionNameOrId`?